# Filter JSON according to multiple categories

Tags: javascript, filter

I need to filter a JSON according to multiple categories that a user can select.

I'm working with a JSON called "news", that is an array of objects. Every object is a news, and has its own array of objects representing a category.

Example of array containing the selected categories :

```
const chosenCategories = ['Category A', 'Category B'];
```

Example of the array containing all the news :

```
[
 {"name": "News A", categories: [{"name": "Category A"}], id: "1"},
 {"name": "News B", categories: [{"name": "Category B"}], id: "2"},
 {"name": "News C", categories: [{"name": "Category C"}], id: "3"}
]
```

A user can select categories, that filters the news to only show the selected categories.
If a user selects "Category A" and "Category B", only the news with theses categories.name will be showed.

I tried this but it doesn't work, even if I select categories, all the news are showed everytime :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (news) {
      setNews(
        news.filter(n => {
          console.log('n ', n);
          if (n.categories.length > 0) { <-- if the news has categories
            chosenCategories.includes(n.categories[0].name); <-- then check if the category is selected
          }
        }),
      );
    }
  }, [chosenCategories]);
```

Comment: filter functions need to return a true or false value; your function doesn't return anything

Comment: What you have there is a JavaScript object. It is not JSON.

Comment: also does your category array inside every news always has a single element?

Comment: @Ramesh yes, always 1 category per news

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value in the filter:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (news) {
      setNews(
        news.filter(n => {
          console.log('n ', n);
          if (n.categories.length > 0) { <-- if the news has categories
            // return true if it includes
            return chosenCategories.includes(n.categories[0].name); <-- then check if the category is selected
          }
          // Return false
          return false
        }),
      );
    }
  }, [chosenCategories]);
```

Comment: thank you, can I make it shorter like this ? 
setNews(news.filter(n => chosenCategories.includes(n.categories[0].name)))

Comment: @Versifiction yes

Comment: @Rieljun Liguid I still got all the news when I select a category even after putting your code

Comment: @Rieljun Liguid I still got all the news when I select a category even after putting your code

Comment: did the code execute when chosenCategories change? if I am not mistaken, you need to add the `news` also in the useEffect array args, sorry I'm in mobile already

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple version of your code.

```js
let chosenCat = ['Category B'];
let newsArray = [
    {"name": "News A", categories: [{"name": "Category A"}], id: "1"},
    {"name": "News B", categories: [{"name": "Category B"}], id: "2"},
    {"name": "News C", categories: [{"name": "Category C"}], id: "3"}
   ];

var filterNews = newsArray.filter(item => item.categories.filter(cat => chosenCat.indexOf(cat.name) > -1).length);
    
filterNews.forEach(news => alert(news.name));
```

Comment: hmm I tried your code but when I select a category, there's still all the news, did I miss something

Comment: I edit the code to choose only 'Category B', the result contains only 'News B'. You can click on "Run code snippet" to test.

Comment: @Versifiction how does `chosenCategories` look like is that an array of strings or an array of objects?

Comment: @Ramesh it's an array of strings like ['Category A', 'Category B']